# I need to make a drop down and drop up like the example included

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I need to create an drop down nav bar(top right) and a drop up button/links (on the top left) like so. the drop down will be displayed once the screen decreases reaches a certain pixel width. adjust the browser to be smaller if you cant see the drop down (NAV).

[image]

They need to be responsive to the size of the browser. This is for a mobile site(iphone and android). Please include a fiddle if possible. or detailed instructions. I don't want to use boot strap or any other platform just Html5 css3 and javascript/jquery. Please include the animation as well.

EXAMPLE:
http://treadsack.com/

How do I make this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: this is not a site to ask people to make your app. Read guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use [**CSS media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to apply different styles when the `viewport/screen` resizes:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
/* if the viewport is less than or equal to 600px hide the div */
    div { display:none; }
}
```

If you have this markup structure:

```
<nav> 
<span>NAV</span>
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>News</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Then CSS would be:

```
ul {
    display:block;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
span {
    display:none;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
    ul {
        display:none;
    }
    li {
        display:block;
    }
    span {
        display:inline;
    }
}
```

Then show/hide the dropdown when you click NAV with:

```
$('span').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/xSey4/).

---

Now when you click the `<span>` again to hide the dropdown then you resize the viewport width greater than **600** the inline menu list is not showing. This is due to the `.slideToggle()`, **js/jQuery** put its styling as an inline attribute `<ul style="">` on the element and that overrides the CSS styling. You can get around with it by declaring `!important` on your CSS to overrule the jQuery styling, but in this case it's not going to be helpful since we are using jQuery to slide the dropdown menu.

A solution would be to handle the `viewport/window` resize via jQuery as well. CSS media queries listens to `window.innerWidth` but this may return a different value on cross browsers (especially older IE). So we need to create a function that returns the `viewport-width`:

```
function viewportWidth() {
    var e = window,
        a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return e[a + 'Width'];
}
```

Then use it on window `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (viewportWidth() <= 600) {
        $('span').show();
        $('ul').hide();
    } else {
        $('ul').show();
        $('span').hide();
    }
});
```

Check this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/xSey4/3/).

Comment: for some reason when the screen reduces on the version that I recreated(copy and pasted from the fiddle) the list is automatically displayed with no nav and click to drop down feature? am i missing some external document link?

Comment: never mind silly question! thanks again pal!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get in the right direction:

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQL5V/), with the following jQuery-code doing the actual job with the menus:

```
var links_are_showing = false;
$("#links").click(function() {
    if (!links_are_showing) { // Link menu is not visible, show
        $("#links_container").slideDown(400);
        $("#main_container").animate({'top':'320px'},400); // Change 400 to any time in ms you want 
        links_are_showing = true;
    } // Link menu is not visible, show
    else { // Link menu is visible, hide
        $("#links_container").slideUp(400);
        $("#main_container").animate({'top':'0'},400); // Change 400 to any time in ms you want 
        links_are_showing = false;
    } // Link menu is visible, hide
}); 


var nav_is_showing = false;
$("#nav").click(function(){
    if (!nav_is_showing) { // Nav menu is not visible, show
        $("#nav_container").slideDown(400); // Change 400 to any time in ms you want 
        nav_is_showing = true;
    } // Nav menu is not visible, show 
    else { // Nav menu is visible, hide
        $("#nav_container").slideUp(400);  // Change 400 to any time in ms you want 
        nav_is_showing = false;
    } // Nav menu is visible, hide
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks alot! This is a great fiddle